# Install second copy of JDK in Websphere 8.5.5.12

Tags: java, websphere

I have installed websphere 8.5.5.12, and j9 sdks 6,7,8. I can through the UI switch between those versions at will. That's all great.

Is it possible to add a second copy of Java 8 into the environment, so that I can for example add changes to the java.security file to test, while having an untouched installation present too.

Ideally I'd like a 4th option to appear in the Gui, rather than manually creating a backup of my Java dir on disk, and switching it in an out.

Answer (score 0):

If you install directly to 8.5.5.12, it will install the Java 8 SDK by default under the java/ directory, then you can install the optional Java 8 SDK offering, which will give you the second Java 8 SDK.  Running the `managesdk.sh -listAvailable` command, it will show you there are 2 Java 8 SDKs and you can switch between them.